# How to build a docker image for jenkins with android and docker build support

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

i'm currently trying to build my own Jenkins docker image with the purpose to have a Jenkins server, that can build Android gradle based projects and docker images.

From my github repo (https://github.com/mikedolx/docker-jenkins-android) this is how my docker file looks like:

```
FROM xmartlabs/android AS android

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl software-properties-common && \
        curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
        add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-cache policy docker-ce && \
        apt-get clean && \
        apt-get install -y docker-ce

FROM jenkins/jenkins

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
COPY --from=android ${ANDROID_HOME} ${ANDROID_HOME}
COPY --from=android /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
COPY --from=android /usr/bin/gradle /usr/bin/gradle
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

# Unfortunately, "chown" flag seems not to be available for COPY in DockerHub.
USER root
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins ${ANDROID_HOME}
USER jenkins

ENV ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT true
```

I have added the needed steps to install docker. I took them from this blog: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04.

I can successfully build the image, and run jenkins server with the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'

services:

  jenkins:
    image: mikedolx/jenkins-android:latest
    container_name: jenkins
    user: jenkins
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
volumes:
  jenkins-data:
```

I have a pipeline project setup to build this image (https://github.com/mikedolx/docker-nextcloud). When i start the build it stops on the second stage, with the following log:

```
[Nextcloud-Github] Running shell script
+ docker build -t mikedolx/nextcloud:14.0.1 --file Dockerfile.14.0 .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Nextcloud-Github@tmp/durable-f5e443ce/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Nextcloud-Github@tmp/durable-f5e443ce/script.sh: docker: not found
```

When i ssh into the jenkins container and try to run "docker", i get the same error.

Questions:

1. how do i build the jenkins docker image to contain the needed binaries to build a docker image?
2. Is this the correct approach to buid a docker image via jenkins?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Could you please help me in the same problem , please check the question once [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i changed the order of installation in my Dockerfile (moved everything after "FROM jenkins/jenkins") i finally had a docker binary in the console. Now when i run my build in jenkins, i get the following error

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

the reason for this is, because i had mapped my host's docker.sock as a volume into my container. But it seems that somehow the permissions are wrong. Need to check this.

EDIT: After i changed the ownership of the hosts /var/run/docker.sock to jenkins:jenkins i was able to perform the required docker command line actions in my jenkins project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run docker in docker.

So, in a nutshell, you mount the host docker socket as a volume into Jenkins and have compatible docker binaries in your container.

This is a [good description](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci)

There is much more to it to consider, such as security depending on other containers running on your host and also how to run it when using jenkins agents.

Comment: I tried to add the docker.sock as a volume to my docker-compose.yml, but i still don't have the docker executable installed within my container. I tried to do that according the instructions in the blog you have linked, but somehow the docker-ce packages seems not to be installed

Comment: you have to exec in and install the packages. Once it restarts then it will all be forgotten again

Comment: after exec into the container as root and running apt-get update && apt-get install docker-ce i get the following message: E: Unable to locate package docker-ce.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Could you please help me on the same problem , please check the question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958)