# How to configure the docker image for the Jenkin to create the Android build?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, docker-image

How can we use the Docker image for the Android and Java SDK instead of setting the manual path of Android and Java inside the *Manage Jenkin* option?

I have done in the **Gitlab** to create the multiple apk on each Git push with the help of **.gitlab-ci.yml**. Is same type of file will be use in case of Jenkin? Please check the below links 
[1). First link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641302/3946958) 
[2). Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64587625/3946958)

Just like **Gitlab** apk/build creation I need to perform same operation in Jenkin.

How to use this below docker image of Android SDK 30 which are as below please check it once

[image]

I am using this Docker image from this reference, please check it once [Click here](https://github.com/docker-android-sdk/android-30)

Comment: could you provide the script you are using in jenkins

Comment: I have not created script right now, can you please guide me on it

Comment: create a pipeline job in jenkins in the following format and perform your operation in build
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clean Workspace') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {

               
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                
            }

        }

    }
}

Comment: Thanks for the update, But I need the docker image in my Jenkin to create the build/apk of android

Comment: ok please give me details i will create a docker file for you which you can use in the above script to build apk

Comment: I am just telling my requirement :- I want to create apk/build on wach push on my git account , for it I need to use the docker image.  I am using this docker [click here](https://hub.docker.com/r/androidsdk/android-30) .. all this set-up i need to do in my local system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236320/discussion-between-farhaan-ahmed-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Comment: @farhaanahmed Any update on it?